# selecting the appropriate regression type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a a diagram which is supposed to use regression because there is a corresponding output for each input. But I am having problem with determining
the appropriate model amongst the regression types.
I know that I can not use Linear regression because of the design, I believe I should be able to make use of polynomial regression.
Please based on the design of the scatter diagram please which regression models would be appropriate for it.

[image]

Comment: Try multiple regressions, pick the one with the highest accuracy/lowest loss

Comment: What do you want to use the regression model for?

Comment: @MattPitkin I want to make predictions about the sales figure for some certain date or ranges of dates and I need some models from which I can select which would make use of the input and make comparison with output on specific date. This data already exist.

Comment: @TomMcLean multiple regression? My dataset only has one variable/feature, I do not know of any way to use multiple regression on it.

Comment: I think he means try out multiple different regression models, i.e., try polynomial models with different orders, and assess them with some metric (e.g., a chi squared goodness of fit test) to see which does best (ideally taking into account the possibility of overfitting with higher order models).

Comment: I'd suggest looking into Gaussian Process regression (e.g., using scikit-learn https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html), potentially just using a [RBF Kernel](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#radial-basis-function-rbf-kernel).

Comment: @MattPitkin Yep that is what I mean. I would also suggest Gaussian Process Regression as well

Comment: @MattPitkin Thanks. I am still a newbie in AI and machine learning. Do u have any suggestion as to any material that can help me go from intro to professional fast. I am a little confused on which type of statistical model to use for my AI since there seems to me **thousands** to choose from

Comment: @TomMclean Thanks. I am still a newbie in AI and machine learning. Do u have any suggestion as to any material that can help me go from intro to professional fast. I am a little confused on which type of statistical model to use for my AI since there seems to me **thousands** to choose from

Comment: To get some hands on experience I'd recommend the series of courses on Kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/learn. They're relatively short, but give a good intro, in particular, to using scikit-learn. The way scikit-learn is built means that it tries to have the same interface to all its models, so you can just swap between them without too much trouble. It's probably also worth just looking through a range of the scikit-learn examples here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/index.html and trying them out yourself.

Comment: @WilliamPage For me I found tutorials very boring and I learned very little from them, it may be different for you. The way I learned was by finding a problem that I found interesting where I could use machine learning to solve it. I learned the gaussian process from a problem where a datset was sparse and highly non-linear/periodic, and the gaussian process fitted well to that dataset. Infact, the data looked very similar to your figure, hence why I recommended it.

Comment: The maths behind the gaussian process is pretty complicated, but really fascinating. I recommend this tutorial if you want to learn how it works https://peterroelants.github.io/posts/gaussian-process-tutorial/